# Which law is someone breaking by using a bathroom of a perceived wrong gender?

Tags: transgender

If a person is allowed to be in a building and use the bathroom, but they decide to use bathroom A when the owner of the facilities believes they belong to gender B:

- What can this person be accused of?
- If they are other user of the bathroom, could other users of the bathroom accuse this person of anything?

Comment: Jurisdiction is especially important in these sorts of social/cultural questions.  Is there a particular area you are interested in?

Answer (score 1):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

In most jurisdictions, there would probably be a decent argument that the person has committed trespass, which typically includes not only entering a property without permission, but entering specific parts of the property without permission.

There are ongoing efforts to address this conduct, so you'll also find [more specific laws in several states](https://www.lgbtmap.org/equality-maps/nondiscrimination/bathroom_bans).

Comment: Com. v. White, 538 A.2d 887 (Pa. Super. Ct. 1988).  A case where a man was convicted of criminal trespass after entering a woman's locker room.

Comment: @MichaelHall it specifies that the owner has allowed them to use bathroom B and implies that the owner does not believe they should be allowed to use bathroom A.

Comment: This is going to depend if the state has laws about bathrooms and gender which some states do. It could violate no laws or it could violate laws depending upon what state it takes place in.

Comment: @MichaelHall I see that you're very committed to this distinction, but I don't think it's really helpful in answering OP's question, which -- as I read it -- is just asking what the most plausible charges might be if the owner got pissy.

Comment: I'd note also that "I haven't experienced or witnessed this" is particularly weak evidence that something hasn't actually happened.

Comment: @MichaelHall the laws for trespassing can apply to rooms or sections of a property and not just the property as a whole.  Such as a room marked "employees only".  The cited case has set the precedent that the sign on the door specifying gender was enough warning to inform the person they weren't allowed to be there.  Now this would require the owner to check and care, and the court to make a decision on the person's gender.  Neither of which seem very likely but still possible depending on location.

Answer (score -3):

Some states may have laws against this type of conduct, I am not sure without looking into it. Primarily, a person could commit a trespass.

For example, a business open to the public is typically considered to be extending a license to the public to use its facilities as it explicitly specifies and, to an extent, implicitly allows. If that business owner informs a patron that it will not permit a person to use the restroom marked for their opposite biological sex at birth, and said person does so regardless, the scope of that license has been exceeded and a trespass has been committed.

Comment: this sounds like a wild guess.

Comment: But disallowing a woman use of the ladies’ restroom because of the way she was born could quite possibly be illegal discrimination.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's correct, but I don't think that's what OP is asking about. The question asks what the bathroom user is likely to be accused of, not for a list of defenses.